# How do I use a replica set seed list with Hibernate and MongoDB

Tags: java, hibernate, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I have an application that is written in Java and was written before by someone else before I got control of it. We are using MongoDB with a replica set. I know that in order to use the replica set properly, you need to pass the driver a "seed list" of all servers associated with the replica set in order for it to choose the primary.

The problem is that the application is using Hibernate to connect to MongoDB. Is there a way to specify the seed list inside the Hibernate xml configuration file? Below is a sample of what we have configured in the application.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">MONGODB</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.mongodb.MongoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database">databasename</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host">192.168.1.10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port">27017</property>
        <mapping resource="mongodb.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I tried to find documentation on the list of properties for this configuration and didn't see anything about specifying multiple hosts for a seed list; `hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host` is the only thing I could find and as far as I know, it only supports 1 host.

Any ideas on how I can make the current application work with a replica set seed list using hibernate?

Comment: I've looked at the code Hibernate uses to connect to MongoDB, and it doesn't look like it supports replica sets, it assumes a single host and port.  [Code here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-ogm/blob/master/mongodb/src/main/java/org/hibernate/ogm/datastore/mongodb/impl/MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java).

Comment: I've done the same and came to the same conclusion. That's rather disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions of Hibernate OGM support this via the property:

```
hibernate.ogm.datastore.host
```

Here's an example of a valid value:

```
www.example.com, www2.example.com:123, 192.0.2.1, 192.0.2.2:123, 2001:db8::ff00:42:8329, [2001:db8::ff00:42:8329]:123
```

The default value is 127.0.0.1:27017. If left undefined, the default port is 27017.

There are more details in the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuring_mongodb)